# How to specify the directory that dask uses for temporary files?

Tags: dask

Dask seems to write to the /tmp folder. How can I change the folder that dask uses for temporary files?

Comment: Can you raise an issue at http://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new ?

Comment: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1659

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `TMPDIR` could potentially cause problems as it might also effect other applications. An alternative is to use [`dask.config.set`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html#directly-within-python)

```
>>> import dask
>>> with dask.config.set({'temporary_directory': '/path/to/tmp'}):
...     pass
```

You could also add the lines

```
temporary_directory: /path/to/tmp
```

to `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml` (in your home directory - see [configuration docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html#specify-configuration))

Comment: If you're getting `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'` with this, see below for my answer.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the accepted code doesn't work for me. I get this error: `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'`

Here's a version that works: `dask.config.set(temporary_directory='/path/to/tmp')`

Also note that you have to do this *before* you create your Client.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the TMPDIR environment variable to the desired location via `export TMPDIR=/my/path` seems to work.