# Dask Distributed Local Directory

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I would like to direct *all* dask temporary data to my fast and big disk at `/mnt/1`. I am running the scheduler like so:

```
dask-scheduler --local-directory /mnt/1
```

and the workers:

```
dask-worker 127.0.0.1:8786 --memory-limit 16GB --nthreads 1 --nprocs 6 --local-directory /mnt/1/
```

My imports look like this:

```py
import dask
from dask import dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client('localhost:8786', set_as_default=True)
dask.config.set(shuffle='disk')
```

And yet, I am still seeing a `partd` directory being created and filled with stuff in my `/tmp` directory, which is not on my fast and big disk.

My question is: how do I tell dask distributed to send *absolutely all* temporary data to `/mnt/1` and not put *anything*  in `/tmp`?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042748/how-to-specify-the-directory-that-dask-uses-for-temporary-files?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work, note the last new line. A bit annoying that the command line flags don't actually do what they suggest they do.

```py
import dask
from dask import dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client('localhost:8786', set_as_default=True)
dask.config.set(shuffle='disk')
dask.config.set({'temporary_directory': '/mnt/1'})
```

Comment: You can set it to your homefolders [dask configuration](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html) also. But yes, a command line option would be nice.