# Set temporary directory: open_mfdataset xarray, dask(?), python

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, tmp

I am opening multiple files with xarray.open_mfdataset and storing them again as one dataset. As I am doing so, my temporary directory runs out of memory.

How do I change the path to the temporary directory?

My code looks something like:

```
    import xarray as xr

    with xr.open_mfdataset( my_list_of_filepaths ) as in_data:

        out_data = some_data_manipulation( in_data )

        out_data.to_netcdf( out_filepath )
```

I have tried:

```
    import dask
    import xarray as xr

    with dask.config.set({'temporary_directory': 'path_to_temp_dir'}):

        with xr.open_mfdataset( my_list_of_filepaths ) as in_data:

            out_data = some_data_manipulation( in_data )

            out_data.to_netcdf( out_filepath )
```

and setting the environment variables TMPDIR, TEMP and TMP to my desired temporary directory without success.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This looks like a great question, but we'll need more information to help. Please see the guide to [ask] and especially how to create a [mre]. But most importantly of all, when asking about errors, be sure to post and [format](/help/formatting) all of your code which leads to the error and post the full [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - it's full of debugging details we (and you!) need to understand the nature of what's going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tries following syntax as well `dask.config.set(temporary_directory='/path/to/tmp')` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62804525/2792888) answer?

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina Thanks for the answer. I also tried that syntax. It unfortunately did not solve it.

Comment: Did you tried to change the yaml configuration file as described in the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/configuration.html)?

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina Yes I tried. Does not solve it either. Maybe it is not a dask issue?

Comment: Just in case I would check the temporary directory permissions as well.

Comment: I also give the argument parallel=True to xarray.open_mf_dataset, but it still does not use my desired temporary directory

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina I have writing permissions in the temp. dir. that I propose.

Answer (score 0):

```
xr.open_mfdataset( my_list_of_filepaths )
```

I believe you must pass at least `chunks={}` to the above call in order for dask to be invoked. You can check whether an array in your returned dataset is wrapping a Dask array or a normal one by checking its `data` attribute:

```
ds = xr.open_...
ds.my_variable.data
```

will either show concrete values (arrays of numbers) or dask.array.Array(...).

Comment: I tried this, also with no success. Setting parallel=True should also invoke dask? My experience is that dask is anyway invoked when "needed", but I might be wrong.

Could it be something related to xarray?

Comment: I believe `parallel` is in the open stage, not the compute stage, so is different. Dask temporary files should have paths including the word "dask".